# selecting group of numbers in a string in python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a list of strings:

```
str_list = ['123_456_789_A1', '678_912_000_B1', '980_210_934_A1', '632_210_464_B1']
```

And I basically want another list:

```
output_list = ['789', '000', '934', '464']
```

It is always going to be the third group of numbers that will always have a `_A` of `_B`

so far I have:

```
import re

m = re.search('_(.+?)_A', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
```

But I keep getting somthing like: `456_789`

Comment: Why not just use `split('_')[2]`?

Comment: `[x.split('_')[2] for x in str_list] `?

Comment: You could map the list, taking the value from this pattern `\d+(?=_[A-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/51No8p/1

Comment: you can try this regex `\d+(?=_A|B)`

Comment: or `r"(\d+)_[AB]"` with your group approach

Comment: So apart from all the details, you want to split on `_` and take the 3rd item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use simple list comprehension for this

```
ans = [i.split("_")[-2] for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match digits followed by an underscore and an uppercase char, you can match the digits and assert the underscore and uppercase char directly to the right.

To match only A or B, use `[AB]` else use `[A-Z]` to match that range.

```
\d+(?=_[AB])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBJLM8/1)

You can use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to find the first occurrence in the string.

```
import re

str_list = ['123_456_789_A1', '678_912_000_B1', '980_210_934_A1', '632_210_464_B1']
str_list = [re.search(r'\d+(?=_[AB])', s).group() for s in str_list]
print(str_list)
```

Output

```
['789', '000', '934', '464']
```

Or using a capturing group version, matching the `_` before as well to be a bit more precise as in your pattern you also wanted to match the leading `_`

```
str_list = [re.search(r'_(\d+)_[AB]', s).group(1) for s in str_list]
```